# Problem saving record with Lightning Data Service, $A.getCallback() error

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-data-service

> ReferenceError: Error in $A.getCallback() [cmp is not defined]
>   Callback failed: serviceComponent://ui.force.components.controllers.recordGlobalValueProvider.RecordGvpController/ACTION$saveRecord

I am creating a clone lightning component that lets the user see a view of an existing records fields, change what they will, then save that new record. After the clicking the save button I got the above error. I have no idea what it is saying.

```
({
handelSaveRecord : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find("ClonedExamCreator").saveRecord($A.getCallback(function(saveResult) {
        if (saveResult.state === "SUCCESS" || saveResult.state === "DRAFT") {
            console.log("Save completed successfully.");
            cmp.set("v.recordSaveError", '');
        } else if (saveResult.state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            console.log("User is offline, device doesn't support drafts.");
            cmp.set("v.recordSaveError", '');
        } else if (saveResult.state === "ERROR") {
           var errMsg = "";
            // console.log('Problem saving record, error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            // saveResult.error is an array of errors,
            // so collect all errors into one message
            for(var i = 0; i < saveResult.error.length; i++) {
                errMsg += saveResult.error[i].message + "\n";
            }
            cmp.set("v.recordSaveError", errMsg);
        } else {
            console.log('Unknown problem, state: ' + saveResult.state + ', error: ' + JSON.stringify(saveResult.error));
            cmp.set("v.recordSaveError", "");
        }   
    }));
}
})
```

---------------- Lightning Page---------------------------

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,flexipage:availableForRecordHome">

<!--<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/> -->

<aura:attribute name="clonedExam" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="clonedExamRecord" type="Object"/>
<aura:attribute name="recordSaveError" type="String"/>

<force:recordData aura:id="ClonedExamCreator"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    layoutType="FULL"
    targetRecord="{!v.clonedExam}"
    targetFields="{!v.clonedExamRecord}"
    targetError="{!v.recordError}"
    fields=""
    mode="EDIT" />  

<!-- Display an editing form -->
<div class="Record Details">
    <lightning:card iconName="action:edit" title="Edit Account">
        <div class="slds-p-horizontal--small">
            <lightning:input label="Name" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Name}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Number of Minutes" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Number_of_Minutes__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Graded" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Graded__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Show One Question at a Time" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Show_One_Question_at_a_Time__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Show Score Upon Completion" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Show_Score_Upon_Completion__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:input label="Randomize Question Order" type="checkbox" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Randomize_Question_Order__c}"/>
            <br/>
            <lightning:select label="Status" value="{!v.clonedExamRecord.Status__c}">
                <option value="Created">Created</option>
                <option value="Sent">Sent</option>
                <option value="Ungraded">Ungraded</option>
                <option value="Graded">Graded</option>
                <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
            </lightning:select>
            <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Clone" iconName="action:new_campaign" onclick="{!c.handelSaveRecord}" />
        </div>
    </lightning:card>
</div>

<!-- Display Lightning Data Service errors, if any -->
<aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.recordError))}">
    <div class="recordError">
        {!v.recordError}
    </div>
</aura:if>
```

Comment: this is a common mistake, when you declare your function "function(component, event, helper)", you need to use the same parameter names. either pass cmp as a parameter or change all your cmp's to component

Comment: @glls Can you post that as an as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake, when you declare your function

> function(component, event, helper)

you need to use the same parameter names.

We can see in your code that you are using `cmp` when attemtping to set an attribute value

> cmp.set("v.recordSaveError".....

either pass `cmp` as a parameter or change all your `cmp`'s to `component`.

E.g.

```
function(cmp, event, helper) {
```